# Virtual terminal not showing data

Tags: pic, uart, proteus, hi-tech-compiler

I am new to PIC programming and I am doing an exercise with UART. After building the program the message is not being displayed. Can someone tell me where I am wrong. BAUDRATE = 9600, _XTAL_FREQ = 20Mhz. My code:

```
void initUART(void)
{
 TRISC6 = 1;        // TX
 TRISC7 = 1;        // RX

 SPBRG = ((_XTAL_FREQ/16)/BAUDRATE) - 1;
 BRGH = 1;      // high baud rate
 SYNC = 0;      // async
 SPEN = 1;      // configure RC6 RC7
 CREN = 1;      // continuous recep.
 SREN = 0;      
 TXIE = 0;
 RCIE = 1;
 TX9 = 0;       // 8-bit txn
 RX9 = 0;       // 8-bit rxn
 TXEN = 0;      // reset tx
 TXEN = 1;      // enable txn
}

void main()
{
 initUART();
 GIE = 1;
 PEIE = 1;

 senddata("Embedded systems");
 while(1){
    //sendbyte(receivebyte());      //when interrupts are disabled
    }
}

void senddata(const unsigned char *data)
{
 while(*data)
    sendbyte(*data++);
}

void sendbyte(unsigned char byte)
{
 while(!TXIF)
    TXREG = byte;
}

/*char receivebyte(void)
{
 if(OERR){
    CREN = 0;
    CREN = 1;
    }
 while(!RCIF);
 return RCREG;
}*/

void interrupt isr(void)
{
 if(RCIF){
    if(OERR){
        CREN = 0;
        CREN = 1;
    }
    sendbyte(RCREG);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the pc? Are you using a true serial port or a usb serial adapter? Do you have a scope?

Comment: I am asked to do it in Proteus. @VladimirCravero

Comment: That's good. Now will you answer my questions?

Comment: @VladimirCravero It seems he is running the code in proteus simulator and using the virtual terminal included in the application. He is not using a real PIC or a physical connection.

Comment: my bad then, I thought that proteus was just a terminal emulatorl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calculating the baud rate for it to be about 4800 on the simulation, even if in reality you'll be transmitting at 9600. Proteus rarely runs at 100% real time during simulation execution and data sync can't be achieved between the simulated devices. This has worked for me before, hope it does for you.

Another thing you might want to double check is that the TX pin from the master goes into the slave's RX pin and vice versa. It's a common connection mix up.

Comment: Fabulous!! I was stuck in displaying the data and I ended up mixing the wires when the correct arrangement was TXD ---> RXD and RXD --> TXD. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Double click the microcontroller,
and where you browse the hex file, check there is option for processor frequency.
Use this frequency as per your code